# How to use c++20 concepts to match a generics member function of a class

Tags: c++, templates, generics, c++20, concept

I have a template class Foo, include a generics function calc which can accept any ARGS

```
template <class RET>
struct Foo
{
    template<class ...ARGS>
    RET calc(ARGS &&...args)
    {
        // do some thing...
        ((std::cout<<", "<<std::forward<ARGS>(args)), ...) <<std::endl;
        return defaultRet;
    }

    RET defaultRet;
};

int main () {
    auto ret = Foo<int>(42).calc(1,2,3); // print "1, 2, 3"
    std::cout<< ret <<std::endl;        // print "42"
    return 0;
}
```

Then I want to write a concepts `Calcable` to match `Foo`. And `Bar::calc` return `void`, so `Calcable<Bar<int>>` should be `false`

But I cannot write the `Calcable`, I'm crazy!

```
template <class RET>
struct Foo
{
    template<class ...ARGS>
    RET calc(ARGS &&...args)
    {
        // do some thing...
        ((std::cout<<", "<<std::forward<ARGS>(args)), ...) <<std::endl;
        return defaultRet;
    }

    RET defaultRet;
};

template <class RET>
struct Bar
{
    
};

template <class T>
concept Calcable = ??  // <<<<<<<<<<<< How to match generics function calc?

template <Calcable T>
struct Check
{

};

int main () {
    auto ret = Foo<int>(3).calc(1,2,3);  // ok
    std::cout<< ret <<std::endl;         // ok

    using YES = Check<Foo<int>>;         // I need compile pass
    using NO = Check<Bar<int>>;          // I need compile error
    return 0;
}
```

I've been looking for it all day, but **nothing**

Comment: So you want to check the return type, for every possible parameter types? I don't think you can do that.

Comment: OK, I deleted Bar::calc. now, I just want to check a type which have a generics calc()

Comment: Still, there's not much you can do. You can check if `calc` is callable with some specific parameter types, but that's it.